# libcurl curl_easy_perform returns OK,but the response callback function was not called

Tags: linux, libcurl

I post a json message to server,and the server supposed to give a response.

when I test server using PostMan,I can get the reponse.

but my linux code `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, respCallBack);`
seems not worked.

here is my headers:

```
    /* add HTTP header */
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept:text/plain");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type:application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Expect:");
```

Here is the curl option:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (void *)param);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, connTimeout);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, respCallBack);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, resp);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, (char *)errbuf);
```

Comment: Is the server returning a body?  Is  CURLOPT_HEADER set?  You might want to post a self-contained example that demonstrate the problem.  self-contained mean it would make sense to give us hard-coded string as shoe in for the server.

Comment: CURLOPT_HEADER is an option that tells curl to send the headers it received to your callback or not.  Next step is update question with a minimal code that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I set the header "Accept:text/plain".Dose it means that I can only handle the repsonses that have no format? If the server give a json reponse,the callback funcion will not work?

Comment: The accept header tells the server what format you want the answer back as.

Comment: I get the response after this change ```headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept:application/json");```Thank you,your comment helps a lot@AllanWind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server did not send a response when client used the header `Accept: text/plain`, but did return a response after that header value was changed to  `application/json`.